# zsh ignores SAVEHIST size

Tags: zsh

Today I made the switch from bash to zsh (+ oh-my-zsh) on my Mac. In bash I kept an `.bash_eternal_history` with over 30k entries. I migrated that into the `.zsh_history` file and format.

Now I set these vars to keep an eternal history in zsh (taken from [1]):

```
HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
HISTSIZE=10000000
SAVEHIST=10000000
setopt BANG_HIST                 # Treat the '!' character specially during expansion.
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY          # Write the history file in the ":start:elapsed;command" format.
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY        # Write to the history file immediately, not when the shell exits.
setopt SHARE_HISTORY             # Share history between all sessions.
setopt HIST_EXPIRE_DUPS_FIRST    # Expire duplicate entries first when trimming history.
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS          # Don't record an entry that was just recorded again.
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS      # Delete old recorded entry if new entry is a duplicate.
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS         # Do not display a line previously found.
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE         # Don't record an entry starting with a space.
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS         # Don't write duplicate entries in the history file.
setopt HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS        # Remove superfluous blanks before recording entry.
setopt HIST_VERIFY               # Don't execute immediately upon history expansion.
setopt HIST_BEEP                 # Beep when accessing nonexistent history.
```

[1] https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273863

But the number in SAVEHIST get's ignored. No matter how high I set it, when I type `echo $SAVEHIST` in my shell, I get `10,000` and my `.zsh_history` file with over 30k entries gets capped at `10,000`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this section from `.zshrc` to `~/opts/args.sh`, and in `.zshrc` I added the line `source ~/opts/args.sh`. That solved it

Answer (score 1):

add `$SAVEHIST` and other hist parameters at the end of `.zshrc`.

(some oh-my-zsh bug)

it helps https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/f29hn4/omz_is_this_a_bug_in_historyzsh/fhf822j